# How to crop image using contour not in Rectangle shape in OpenCV Java?

Tags: java, image, opencv

I just learn OpenCV about 2 weeks ago and planning to use it on my Spring project with java wrapper. I want to **crop image based on its shape and embed it into a pure white background.** I already tried several method from internet (HSV average comparison, cropping using standard ROI, masking, etc) and decided to use these steps which i got from some forum :

1. Convert the img to grayscale
2. Threshold it to a binary image
3. Use findContours to get the actual outline
4. Crop the image based on the contour result

I hope anyone can help me on this matter or maybe guide to using another method, thank you very much.

example image source :
[Image Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZSgm.jpg)

current extracted result using Rectangle ROI (**the code is not contain on the below section because i'm trying to change the method**) : [Cropped Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mifxv.png)

Here what I tried (using OpenCV 3.2.0) :

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

// Reading the Image from the file and storing it in to a Matrix object
String file ="C:/EXAMPLES/OpenCV/smartphone.jpg";
Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread(file); 

Mat srcClone = new Mat(); // clone it so it won't affect the original image
Imgproc.cvtColor(src, srcClone, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY); // convert the color to gray

Double threshold =  Imgproc.threshold(srcClone, srcClone, 50, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

// add gaussian blur effect to reduce noises
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(srcClone, srcClone, new Size(5,5), 0);

//find the edges using Canny
Mat edges = new Mat();
Imgproc.Canny(srcClone, edges, 100, 200);

//find the Contour based on Canny result
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
final Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(edges, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL , Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

//don't know the next step if not using Rectangle ROI
...
```

Comment: what else do you want? Images are always rectangular region. Do you want to hide the background (alpha channel)? Do you want to make the background black? Can you give us a sample manually created image showing what you want to achieve?

Comment: ah ok, you want to make the background white... draw that contour filled with black color on a white CV_8UC1 mask image. Then use src.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(255), mask). Then crop the ROI.

Comment: @Micka Thank you, i changed some code, use your suggestion on it and it works!

Comment: write an answer witj your final code if you like to :)